# Is auto ever useful in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, keyword

Has anyone ever seen the storage class `auto` explicitly used in C/C++? If so, in what situation?

Comment: @Graham I dunno, I'd say that's a completely different question. Note that the feature that this particular question is asking about disappeared in C++11 so it's not surprising that there have been no "updates" in the intervening years (aside from the sole non-2008 answer that you mentioned, which incidentally is answering the wrong question)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough. I'll retract my flag, but I still think it's useful for those stumbling upon this question, so it should probably be in 'Related:'-style comment.

Comment: @Graham Could be

Comment: Related, for those in C++11 or later: [C++ auto keyword. Why is it magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7576953/8117067)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

auto is never useful in current C/C++ because all variables are implicitly auto. It is useful in C++0x, where it can replace the type declaration entirely - if you have a variable with an initial assignment, 'auto' will just make it the type of that assignment value, as in the comments.

Comment: Could you include an example of C++0x use?

Comment: auto funcptr = std::tr1::bind(&Foo::Bar, this, _1, _2); This declares "funcptr" to be of the same type as "bind" returns (which is a seriously complicated type; in old days, you'd wrap it up in a std::tr1::function template, but with auto you don't need to do that anymore).

Comment: Is this a special case or does it work more in general, like

auto someVar = functionThatReturnsUnknownType();

?

Comment: It works in general. Basically it's allowing variable type deduction at the initialization/construction site. The compiler already does this for templates ( template<class T> void foo(T t); ) and 'auto' makes it happen in function bodies.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen `auto` used in code written in the last 10+ years. There is no reason to use `auto` since the only places you *can* use it is where it is implied anyway.  The only reason it still exists is for backwards compatibility but it should be avoided in new code.

Answer (score 3):

In GCC you might need auto to declare nested function in order to be able to define it anywhere in function body - see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

Comment: Right at the top of that page it says that nested functions are not supported for GNU C++. So does the auto stuff regarding nested functions apply to other implementions of C++?

Comment: @c0m4: It would be safest to assume that GNU C extensions like nested functions are not available with other compilers.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's assumed if you omit the class specifier.  The only reasonable uses I can think of would be to call attention to a particular local variable that overrides, say, a global variable with the same name, or as an interview question.

Chances are, you'll confuse the poor programmer who's stuck maintaining the code!

Answer (score 1):

As Alex has covered, auto is used in C++0x to declare types in initialisation declarations where the type is inferred from the initialisation code.

There was a proposal for it to also be used as a return type, where the type is deduced from code returning a value. However this gave rise to an ambiguity so, at time of writing, something more consistent with C++0x's lambda syntax is being considered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from my code, written in C++11:

```
c_srgb find_in_book(const c_HVC &HVC) {
    auto b = munsell.mun_to_rgb_book.find(HVC);
    if( b != munsell.mun_to_rgb_book.end()) {
        c_srgb f = b->second;
        return f;
    } else {
        c_srgb ret;
        ret.r=ret.g=ret.b=0;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I prefer that to this:

```
c_srgb find_in_book(const c_HVC &HVC) {
std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<dj::color::c_HVC,dj::color::c_srgb,std::less<dj::color::c_HVC>,std::allocator<std::pair<const dj::color::c_HVC,dj::color::c_srgb>>,false>>> b = munsell.mun_to_rgb_book.find(HVC);
    if( b != munsell.mun_to_rgb_book.end()) {
        c_srgb f = b->second;
        return f;
    } else {
        c_srgb ret;
        ret.r=ret.g=ret.b=0;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not "the storage class `auto`" that the question's asking about.