# What does the auto c++ keyword do?

Tags: c++, auto, fmod

I recently came accross the keyword auto in c++.

In the code:

```
auto maxIterator = std::max_element(&spec[0], &spec[sampleSize]);
float maxVol = *maxIterator;

// Normalize
if (maxVol != 0)
  std::transform(&spec[0], &spec[sampleSize], &spec[0], [maxVol] (float dB) -> float { return dB / maxVol; });
```

This is to do with running a frequency analysis on a audio stream.
From the website: http://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/cutting-your-teeth-on-fmod-part-4-frequency-analysis-graphic-equalizer-beat-detection-and-bpm-estimation/

I have searched the forums but It says that there is no use for the keyword. Could someone please explain the use of it here.

I am quite new to c++ so please try not to make the answers too complicated.
Thanks so much all.

Did auto make maxIterator a pointer also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576953/c-auto-keyword-why-is-it-magic?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Compiler guess `maxIterator`'s type. If `spec`'s type is `float []`, `maxIterator` type is `float *`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, the keyword `auto` deduces the type of declared variable from its initialization expression. Hence, in your code it deduces type of `maxIterator`.

For more information on `auto` look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz.aspx)