# what is C++: auto = [] syntax

Tags: c++

I saw the following code while doing some leetcode in prep for interview season:

```
auto select = [](const string& log)
        {
            auto index = log.find(' ') + 1;
            return ::isalpha(log[index]);
        };
```

what is the function of the `auto select = []` more specifically the `auto = []` part

interestingly, this function was able to be used as a predicate in an STL function

Comment: look at this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda, it was useful for me

Comment: [C++ meaning of \[ \]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22327248/995714), [What does the auto c++ keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21226402/995714)