# What is the difference between Automatic type deduction in C++11 and type casting

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, typecasting-operator

I am getting confused between two concepts that is "auto" keyword that is introduced in C++11 and type casting (dynamic_cast/static_cast).

Does "auto" keyword in C++11 uses type casting internally?

Comment: It uses template rules to determine the type.

Comment: `auto` literally just "deduces" the type for you so you don't have to write it yourself, it never changes the type of a value by itself. It can only be used in places where the compiler can infer the type from the context ([more info here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)). Type casting involves changing the type of the value, and you have to tell in your program what is the new type that you want to use the value as (more info [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)).

Comment: These are two different concepts. Casting is used when you want to treat a value of some type as a value of another type (e.g., treat an integer value as a floating-point value). Type deduction allows you to deduce type, for instance when you want to declare a variable being of type of its initializer expression `auto i = 1;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ auto keyword. Why is it magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576953/c-auto-keyword-why-is-it-magic)

Comment: One of the advantages of `auto` is that by using it, you can be sure there won't be any implicit conversions when you initialize it. It's nearly the opposite of a cast. Perhaps you are confusing `auto` with [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's keep it simple using an example

```
unsigned short s = 65535;
auto positive = s;
auto negative = (short) s;

std::cout << positive << std::endl; // prints 65535
std::cout << negative << std::endl; // prints -1
```

In this code:

- In the first line you just initialize a `unsigned short` variable with value `655355`
- In the second line you initialize the variable `positive` and you **let the compiler deduce its type** from its initializer (see [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)). Therefore `positive` will be `unsigned short` because its initializer has that type.
- In the third line, `negative`'s type will be deduced as `short`, because you are casting the type of `s` from `unsigned short` to `short`.

Note that both `positive` and `negative` variables will hold the same value, which in hexadecimal is `0xffff`, but they are interpreted in different ways due to their types.

So there's not such a thing as a difference between auto and casting as if they were comparable, they are different concepts.

- `auto` will deduce the type or your variable based on certain rules
- casting will change the type of your variable

I recommend you to read *Effective Modern C++* by Scott Meyers to learn about how `auto` works.

Comment: Maybe this is a bad place to ask, but is that book recommendation suitable for a beginner? I had put it on my reading list, but I was assuming it was more advanced.

Comment: Well maybe you are right, but he gives a very good explanation about the type deduction.