# How to Point to a Function in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I want to know, how to create a **pointer** that points to the **address** of a function.

Supose that we have the following **function**:

```
int doublex(int a)
{
    return a*2;
}
```

I already know that `&` is used to get the **address**. How could I point to this function?

Comment: The function name itself is the address you want.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `&function_name`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to call a function via a pointer?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yes, but I do not know how to assign this address to the pointer. I just have do "pointer = & function_name"?

Comment: `auto pointer_to_function = &function;`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes

Comment: @Grandtour You simply do `function_pointer(parameters)`.

Comment: Also note that you don't even need the `&`. Example: `int foo(int x) {return x*2;} int main(int (*ptr)(int); ptr = foo; std::cout << ptr(1);)`.

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not a substitute for a C++ book. Someone who wants to learn how to use function pointers will find far more information in a good C++ book, then from a brief comment on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I didn't knew that. I thought that "&" was the only way to get the address.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The `&` operator can only be omitted for non-member functions.

Comment: Specifically for functions it's optional. (For non-member functions, as Some programmer dude mentions.)

Comment: Actually one should always believe that "&" is the only way to get the address; it's something automagically help you turn the function name into address, just like array name. Happy programming.

Comment: Why don't you guys put the answer? Is there anything in this question that doesn't make it clear?

Comment: Cause @Someprogrammerdude thought that the solution was `auto pointer_function = &double;`

Comment: For "Why don't you guys put the answer?", hmm, [it's a bug I think](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/421325). (the first comment)

Comment: Handy reading: [Is the type of “pointer-to-member-function” different from “pointer-to-function”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said, you can just take the address with the `&` operator. Then the easiest way is to assign it with a `auto` variable to store it, now you can use your variable like a function itself.

```
int doubleNumber(int x)
{
    return x*2;
}

int main()
{
  auto func = &doubleNumber;
  std::cout << func(3);
}
```

See a live example **[here](http://cpp.sh/8oglb)**

Comment: This is right, but in my case, the pointer was declared using "malloc"

Comment: and what's your point? You should give a more precise context of what you're asking

Comment: That's because I'm always confused in how to use malloc, so I didn't put the declaration of the pointer in my answer.

Comment: @Grandtour begin with not using malloc if you're writing C++.

Comment: Oh, yes, I tought that I was still programming C, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Can you explain what is the "auto" type in your answer? This is only the remaining thing to I accept your answer.

Comment: It's quite OT, but anyway. **auto specifier**: _For variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer._   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: To do this in C, is it the same way?

Comment: @Grandtour auto here is deduced as (an unconfortable) `int (*)(int) func;` so the same as a C function pointer. see here https://cppinsights.io/

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
auto function_pointer = &doublex;
```

And what is the **auto** type?

> The auto keyword specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deducted from its initializer. In case of functions, if their return type is auto then that will be evaluated by return type expression at runtime. **[Source here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-inference-in-c-auto-and-decltype/)**

This will help you: [C++ auto keyword. Why is it magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576953/c-auto-keyword-why-is-it-magic)

Comment: Judging by the comments, OP wants to know how to call a function pointer.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 so how would I get the address?

Comment: @Grandtour The point is that `double` is not a valid function name. Neither are `int`, `return`, etc.

Comment: For modern C++, I believe we should always use what @Some programmer dude said. But you may also try `int (*ptr)(int) = funct_name_and_Im_not_keyword;` (or adding a `&` before it) to be a cool guy.

Comment: So the program will return compilation error, right?

Comment: @Grandtour Why won't you try it? It will.

Comment: So, I think I will change the function_name to be more right

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and store references to compatible functions or pass your function as parameter in another function.

```
typedef int (*my_function_type)(int a);
int double_number(int a)
{
    return a*2;
}
my_function_type my_function_pointer = double_number;
int transform_number(int target, my_function_type transform_function) {
    return transform_function(target);
}
```

I hope it helps you