# Simultaneously infer multiple types with 'auto'

Tags: c++

I tried the following

```
auto ns=ms.capture[0].init,nl=ms.capture[0].len;
```

because I was too lazy to lookup what the types of the `init` and `len` fields were. The compiler didn't like it of course.

My understanding is that:

```
ttt xx,yy;
```

is equivalent to

```
ttt xx;ttt yy;
```

So should the same work for `auto`? That is, shouldn't

```
auto xx, yy;
```

Become:

```
auto xx, auto yy;
```

Or there is something I don't understand in detail? Or is there something wrong with my compiler?

Comment: Better read about `auto` [here[(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

Comment: `auto` is not magic (well it is but not as much as you wish). You can think of `auto` like a placeholder for the actual type that is replaced by the compiler. Its not possible to replace `auto` in your code with the "correct" type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++11 "auto" semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542873/c11-auto-semantics)

Comment: You can get detailed information from this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576953

Comment: *Or there is something I don't understand in detail?*  Yes.

Comment: btw, maybe you would collect less downvotes if you summarized what you found in documentation and what makes you believe that your code should work. Currently the question reads like "I want it to work like that but it does not."

Answer (score 6):

`auto` is a placeholder for type deduction. In your case here, it is deduced from the initializer.

As you said:

```
T1 a, b;
```

is equivalent to:

```
T1 a; T1 b; // (A)
```

but **not equivalent** to:

```
T1 a; T2 b; // (B)
```

Hence, when you write:

```
auto ns=ms.capture[0].init,nl=ms.capture[0].len;
```

The compiler struggles to determine the underlying type because the `init` member is a `const char *` and the `len` member is an `int` (according to your error message). You gave two initializers with different types. We are in the case *(B)* of the above examples.
Consequently, the type deduction fails.

To make it simple, your code would be valid if it is possible to replace the `auto` specifier with an actual type (which isn't the case here).

Answer (score 3):

As you said, (and [Fareanor said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67368341/27678))

```
ttt xx,yy;
```

is equivalent to

```
ttt xx;ttt yy;
```

So it's not possible for

```
auto xx,yy = ...;
```

to deduce

```
char* xx, int yy = ...;
```

`auto` in the way you wrote it is only able to infer *one* type. What you are looking for is "tuple initialization". I say it like that within quotes because it's not a real thing, but there's a common pattern in C++ and other languages that looks like what you're doing.

For example, in **Python**:

```
xx, yy = "foo", 42
```

Will indeed initialize `xx` and `yy` as you'd expect.

In C++ pre-C++17 you could *kind of* achieve this via tuple assignment:

```
char* xx;
int yy;
std::bind(xx, yy) = std::make_tuple("foo", 42);
```

(And C# works pretty much the same way). It's not great; you are forced to declare your types, then wrap references to them in a tuple via `bind`, and finally perform assignment. Meaning you don't get to take advantage of copy elision, and your types either need to be default-constructible or else you call a constructor with meaningless parameters.

However, **post C++17** we can use **[Structured Bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)** where we can get type inference, copy elision, and all that good stuff.

Now we can say:

```
auto [xx, yy] = // array/tuple-like/POD-type
```

And we will get appropriate types for `xx` and `yy`. Here's an example approximating the code you posted:

```
struct Member{
    const char* init = "foo";
    int len = 42;
};

struct Test{
    std::vector<Member> capture{Member{}};
};

int main()
{
    Test ms;
    auto [ns, nl] = ms.capture[0];
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s14Ksf3PE)

Comment: Wow +1, I wasn't aware of this syntax (Structure bindings) ! :)

Comment: @Fareanor: :-) It makes me happy to know I helped you learn something today.